# React native filter array not working on string

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am having issues trying to filter an array of message objects. I do not want to include the objects with "_id" value "receiver" or "blockedUsers".

Array of message objects:

```
[
  {"_id":"receiver"},
  {"_id":"blockedUsers"},
  {"_id": MjIzx3XA1mpcuzgDVZj","createdAt":1631349363111,"text":"Ok","user":{"name":"Nikki","_id":"M6fBsPludfYVjJXKYvwgxHRacYw1"}},
  {"_id":" MjG3hFAgcNweJWh9SF7","createdAt":1631300277391,"text":"Again","user":{"name":"Chris","_id":"tFhmw5oQoPhk8nF2sx5rE5BFqw93"}
 }
]
```

The following doesn't seem to work

```
this.state.messages.filter(msg => !msg._id.includes("receiver") || !msg._id.includes("blockedUsers")).
```

The original array is returned.

But if I use this

```
this.state.messages.filter(msg => msg._id.includes("receiver") || msg._id.includes("blockedUsers"))
```

it returns:

```
[{"_id":"receiver"},{"_id":"blockedUsers"}]
```

Can you please assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter condition is wrong, it will always return true in your case.
[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback should return `true` for the items you want to keep.

You have to use AND `&&` instead of OR `||`.

```
this.state.messages.filter(msg => 
!msg._id.includes("receiver") && !msg._id.includes("blockedUsers")
)
```

Why it initially returned true? Because when the id is "receiver", it doesn't include "blockedUsers" and the other way around. You want to keep the element if it doesn't include "receiver" AND it also doesn't include "blockedUsers".

Here is a truth table to make it more clear, it should be `true` for the items you want to keep.

| !includes("receiver") | !includes("blockedUsers") | OR | AND |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| false | false | **false** ✅ | **false** ✅(skip item, it includes both strings) |
| false | true | **true** ❌ | **false** ✅(skip item, it includes "blockedUsers") |
| true | false | **true** ❌ | **false** ✅(skip item, it includes "receiver") |
| true | true | **true** ❌ | **true** ✅(this is the only case where you want to keep the item, when it doesn't include either string) |

Comment: Just: `arr.filter(({ _id }) => !['receiver', 'blockedUsers'].includes(_id))`

Comment: @YosvelQuinteroArguelles Yes, you can make the check a lot shorter and nicer-looking if needed. I tried to focus the answer more on why it is wrong, not on how it can be improved.

Comment: Have to note that `['receiver', 'blockedUsers'].includes(_id))` does a different thing than the `includes` function OP was using. The `includes` he was using was [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) which also returned true if the id was "receivers" or some other strings that contain the given needles. I am not sure if that's what OP needed or not, but it's important to note they return different values on various inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const arr = [{ _id: 'receiver' },{ _id: 'blockedUsers' },{ _id: 'MjIzx3XA1mpcuzgDVZj', createdAt: 1631349363111, text: 'Ok', user: { name: 'Nikki' } },{ _id: 'M6fBsPludfYVjJXKYvwgxHRacYw1' },{ _id: ' MjG3hFAgcNweJWh9SF7', createdAt: 1631300277391, text: 'Again', user: { name: 'Chris', _id: 'tFhmw5oQoPhk8nF2sx5rE5BFqw93' }}]

const result = arr.filter(({ _id }) => !['receiver', 'blockedUsers'].includes(_id))

console.log(result)
```