# How to take three different words from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, filter

I want to create a function taking three random different words from an array

I followed [React native filter array not working on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143016/react-native-filter-array-not-working-on-string) to filter the array. However, the filter is not working.

```
takeThreeWords=()=>{
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    rand =(max, min=0)=> Math.floor(Math.random()*max-min)
    randomWord=()=> this.state.wordsBank[rand(this.state.wordsBank.length)]
    let aRandomWord = randomWord()
    
    this.setState(prevState=>({
      wordsToUse:[...prevState.wordsToUse, aRandomWord],
      wordsBank: prevState.wordsBank.filter(word=>word!== aRandomWord)

    }))
```

The last line is to make sure that no words from wordsBank are taken twice. However, the function works just as if the last line does not exist. wordsToUse take three words, but sometimes they are the same...

Can you please point me out what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating `wordsBank` via `this.setState`, but your loop keeps operating on the initial copy of `wordsBank`, which has not been filtered.

The cleanest fix is to not call `this.setState` multiple times in a loop.

```js
let wordsBank = this.state.wordsBank;
let extractedWords = [];
while(extractedWords.length<3) {
  let i = ~~(Math.random()*wordsBank.length);
  extractedWords.push(wordsBank.splice(i, 1)[0]);
}

this.setState(prevState=>({
  wordsToUse: [...prevState.wordsToUse, ...extractedWords],
  wordsBank
}));
```

Comment: You are amazing. Such a fast answer, and it works perfectly. Thank you so much